# Nesting lists in python 2.7 (list of list)

Tags: python, list, nested

I need to create a list of lists.  I've included some code leading up to where I am having problems. masterList at the bottom is the desired output.  I have tried to explain my code and demonstrate the steps for a clear understanding.

```
storeTask = list(islice((t for t in list5 if t[1] == 'Tasked'), 3))
```

print storeTask returns this:

```
[['Acq666666', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY','XXXX', ['367179', 'Image  6'], ['367179', 'VID 12']], ['Acq777777', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-XXXX', 'XXXX ', ['367194', 'Image  1'], ['367194', 'VID 5']], ['Acq888888', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20xx-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', ['367195', 'VID 9']]]
```

I loop through storeTask  and count the elements.  If the count is 8, I delete the first element of the second nested list.

```
for st in storeTask:
taskedL = len(st)
if taskedL == 6: pass
if taskedL == 7: pass
if taskedL == 8:
   longList = st[7]
   del(longList[0])
```

print st returns this:

```
['Acq666666', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', ['367179', 'Image  6'], ['VID 12']]
['Acq777777', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', ['367194', 'Image  1'], ['VID 5']]
['Acq888888', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', ['367195', 'VID  9']]
```

To remove the nested lists I use flatten

```
mstock = flatten(st)
```

print mstock returns:

```
['Acq666666', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367179', 'Image  6', 'VID 12']
['Acq777777', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367194', 'Image  1', 'VID 5']
['Acq888888', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367195', 'VID  9']
```

This is exactly the results I need. However, I need to get these lists back into a master list. Below is what I would like the output to be:

```
masterList = [
['Acq666666', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367179', 'Image  6', 'VID 12']
['Acq777777', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367194', 'Image  1', 'VID 5']
['Acq888888', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367195', 'VID  9']
]
```

** I have tried to create an empty list and append them but the result produces this for each list:

```
[['Acq888888', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367195', 'VID  9']] 
[['Acq666666', 'Tasked', 'Location', 'Movie', '20XX-MM-YYYY', 'XXXX', '367179', 'Image  6', 'VID 12']]
```

**I have asked a similar question but have not been able to use with an success.**

Comment: Perhaps with the code that generated the last result someone could identify where it went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional code would be helpful, would something like the following solve your problem?

```
masterList = [flatten(st) for st in storeTask]
```